# Removing an list from a list of list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I would like to loop through list of lists in the dictionary and delete certain lists based on a value in the list being equal to `None`. My code is below. Rather than deleting the list that meets the condition, it's always deleting the first list.

My code:

```
My_Table = {
    'Table1' : {'Results': [["pineapple", 5], ["cherry", 7], ["kumquat", None], ["plum", None]]},
    'Table2' : {'Results': [["Orange", 5], ["Apple", 7], ["Pear", None], ["cantelope", None]]},
}

for tbl, values in My_Table.viewitems():
      for item_values in values['Results']:
        if item_values[1] is not None:
            values['Results'].remove(item_values)
      print values['Results']
```

Output:

```
[['Apple', 7], ['Pear', None], ['cantelope', None]]
[['cherry', 7], ['kumquat', None], ['plum', None]]
```

Desired Output:

```
[['Orange', 5], ['Apple', 7]]
[['pineapple', 5], ['cherry', 7]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never remove items from a sequence while iterating over it.  Doing so screws up Python's iteration protocol and often causes it to accidentally skip items.

Instead, you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and slice assignment:

```
for tbl, values in My_Table.viewitems():
    values['Results'][:] = [x for x in values['Results'] if x[1] is not None]
    print values['Results']
```

Demo:

```
>>> My_Table = {
...     'Table1' : {'Results': [["pineapple", 5], ["cherry", 7], ["kumquat", None], ["plum", None]]},
...     'Table2' : {'Results': [["Orange", 5], ["Apple", 7], ["Pear", None], ["cantelope", None]]},
... }
>>> for tbl, values in My_Table.viewitems():
...      values['Results'][:] = [x for x in values['Results'] if x[1] is not None]
...      print values['Results']
...
[['Orange', 5], ['Apple', 7]]
[['pineapple', 5], ['cherry', 7]]
>>>
```

Unlike your current code, this will first build a new list which contains all of the items that we want to keep. Afterwards, it will transfer these items into the old list using slice assignment.

The `[:]` makes this an in-place operation.  Meaning, the `values['Results']` object is only modified, not replaced.  Had we done this instead:

```
values['Results'] = [x for x in values['Results'] if x[1] is not None]
```

the code would still work, but the list would be replaced with the new one made from the comprehension.

Comment: Could you please explain how reassigning with [:] works, and why that's correct? Thanks

Comment: There, I added an explanation.

Comment: @iCodez Actually list slice assignment converts the object on RHS [to a list](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/98ee845a139a/Objects/listobject.c#l646) under the hood using [`PySequence_Fast`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/sequence.html#c.PySequence_Fast). i.e No laziness or memory advantage here.

Comment: @iCodez Thank you, but I still don't get something - You say "the object is modified, not replaced". But OP didn't replace the list either, he only modified it by using the replace() function. I still don't quite get the difference, and why what you did was legal but what he did wasn't. By using [:] you create a new copy of the list in values['Results'], meaning you replace it... Is that correct?

Comment: @thomas: You are correct that the OP's solution modified the list.  The difference is that he was modifying it while also iterating over it.  My solution however modifies the list *after* I iterate over it to get the values I want.  Also, `[:]` does not make a copy in this case.  It tells Python to use slice assignment.  `[:]` only makes a copy when it is on the left of the `=` (a.k.a part of an expression), as in `copy = mylist[:]`.